# Tabulator.js: get/select rows on current page

Tags: javascript, pagination, tabulator

I am using an amazing tabulator plugin for managing tabular data, API is very clear and reliable but i cant do a very simple thing: get/select all rows on current page.

Custom row selection can look like this:

```
table.selectRow(table.getRows().filter(row => <<Custom Selection>>);
```

Where Custom selection has to respect the current page, but i dont get from where i can take it.

Maybe i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that directly form Tabulator, but is should be fairly easy to do yourself with a bit of JavaScript.

First you want to get the rows that are visible on that page:

```
var pageRows = table.getRows(true);
```

Then you want to get the selected rows

```
var selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
```

then you want to find rows that exist in both arrays, these will be the selected rows on that page:

```
var rows = selectedRows.filter(value => -1 !== pageRows.indexOf(value));
```

Comment: Hi, Oli, thanks for your reply! My issue is a little bit different. I want to select (e.g. using button) only rows on the current page. So i dont have the initial selection and .getSelectedRows() returns an empty array. Also AFAIK .getRows(true) returns all rows that are filtered, not the visible rows on page.

Comment: ive found table.rowManager.getDisplayRows() which exactly does what i need. Is it okay to use this method?

Comment: okay i see, ive deleted my "answer". But is there any safe way to make it work? Page-wise table processing is rather common thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column name of your index is 'id' you can do the following:

```
var selectedData = table.getSelectedData();
jQuery.map(selectedData, function(value, index) {
    console.log(value.id);
});
```